# Where can I find yak butter online or in NYC?

Tags: butter

I was told by a Nepalese acquaintance that it's not available. Seems unlikely.

Answer (score 3):

Often finding exotic ingredients means determining which cultures use that ingredient, determining where there's a high concentration of immigrants from those regions, and checking for stores in that area.

In this particular case, we know that yak is a staple of Nepalese cuisine, and searching for Nepalese restaurants in New York City, we find a cluster of about 8 near the intersection of Roosevelt Ave & 74th St.  There's a smaller cluster of three on Queens Blvd. between 39th Pl & 50th St.

... and just searching for 'nepalese groceries nyc' finds [Himalayan Mini Mart](http://www.yelp.com/biz/himalayan-mini-mart-woodside), which is sort of between those two clusters (39th Ave & 64th St.)  There was also [an article on the growing 'Little Nepal' in Jackson Heights](http://www.nydailynews.com/new-york/queens/nepal-immigrants-finding-new-home-queens-article-1.156374).  Following a few leads in that article, I also found a [Himalaya Bazaar](http://www.yelp.com/biz/himalaya-bazaar-queens) closer to that larger cluster of restaurants.